# How to define my own HTML5 elements and still be valid

Tags: html

I've run out of elements to use and need some more. How can I define my own HTML tags, like  `<x>` or `<y>` and make them work correctly with browsers?

Comment: "I've run out of elements to use and need some more"... how have you managed that?

Comment: Why are you calling your elements as HTML5 elements?

Answer (score 5):

You don't.  In fact, I'm not even sure what you mean by "run out of elements".  Browsers will not render unfamiliar tags.  Consider using properly-named classes or IDs mixed with the most appropriate elements available.

Answer (score 4):

To define your own HTML 5 elements and still be valid you should join the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG) and suggest alterations to the spec.

Comment: Did that but they don't want to listen to me :(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define your own HTML5 tags. There is a way you *can* use invalid tags, though I don't advise it.

Modern browsers treat invalid tags as inline elements. Older browsers do not display them, but if you use HTML5 shiv, shim, or modernizr, it will force old browsers to treat them the same way.

Again, it is recommended to stick with valid HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a predefined standard, so no you can't just define your own elements. You can read more about the standards [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/).

Perhaps you are thinking of XML, but in that case you should provide more detail so we can understand what you are trying to achieve with these elements.

Comment: Can I put xml in a html page, and style the xml tags with CSS?

Comment: @thelolcat - What are you actually trying to achieve? What is the problem with the comprehensive set of native elements? We will be able to help you far better if you explain the issue in more detail.

Comment: @thelolcat +1 to what James has said: You really need to provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well my app builds a page with lots of info and it needs 10 elements or so for displaying content. Most of them are nested. Now I'm using all one-letter tags, but they are not enough :) I'd like to avoid using elements with longer names or attributes because they considerably increase the size of the HTML. Think of it like a complex math formula that I need to style...

Comment: Use `<div>` or `<span>` tags with classes to do styling like that.

Comment: @thelolcat I think we're all a bit confused here still. This sounds like a pretty basic page you are trying to create, and one that should be achievable with basic HTML. HTML is designed to be nested, and indeed its structure depends on it. As such, I can't determine what you are trying achieve that can not be done with normal HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

Use [x-Tags](http://www.x-tags.org/) by Mozilla. Validity might be an issue, but you get cross-browser (even IE 9+) support for the tag.

(Sorry to spoil the fun post.)

Comment: Yeah @Boldewyn, no fun ;)